# Java AMF serialization

Tags: java, flash, blazeds, amf

I'm migrating from Drupal to Java.

I need to create a servlet to serve existing Flash player with server data.

Until now this was done with AMFPHP module.

I'm looking for a way to serialize a simple class.

OpenAMF seems like a good choice but I can't find any documentation or an example.
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: I always use Json to serialize

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS)

Highly configurable, good documentation ( open-sourced by Adobe ), servlet-based ( the BlazeDS serializer / deserializer is essentially a MessageBrokerServlet ) and it comes with the advantages of AMF -- faster, allows long-polling, push technologies etc.

Fairly easy to set up and begin using as well.

Comment: I'd challenge the 'good documentation' assertion. I found it poorly documented with no clear instructions on how to extend it to support custom type handling.

Comment: Thanks Kal, but I'm looking for a simple sterilizer, and that's it. BlazeDS seems like an overkill

Answer (score 0):

In theory, BlazeDS is the place to start as it is the official Adobe solution and it's open source. There's also [GraniteDS](http://www.graniteds.org/), which I think has better documentation and this is where I'd start if I was doing it all over again.

If you go with BlazeDS, then I recommend the book [Enterprise Development with Flex](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596154172) as the only decent source of information when you need to customize BlazeDS.

Comment: Thanks Steve, but I'm looking for a simple sterilizer, and that's it. GraniteDS and BlazeDS seems like an overkill

Comment: OpenAMF looks dead - no updates for 2 years. Look at wikipedia for a list Java implementations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format

Comment: Personally, I think you'll spend a lot of time doing the research when you could get either BlazeDS or GraniteDS up-and-running in the same amount of time.

Comment: Thanks Steve.I found code.google.com/p/amf-serializer/ This looks good